# Maintain reference in jQuery.clone() element to original element

Tags: javascript, jquery

I was surpised to see the jQuery did not include any functionality in the resulting element of a `$.clone()` operation to recall the source element. My work-around was to simply include the jQuery object of the original element in the clone's data store like this

```
var $elOriginal = $('SomeUniqueSelector');
var $elClone = $elOriginal);

// Save a jQuery object of the original element in the 
// clone's data store
$elClone.data('original', $elOriginal);
```

When I need to reference the original, I dig into my clone's data store,

```
$elOriginal = $elClone.data('original');
```

Personally, I'm not thrilled with this approach. (Of course I considered tagging the original element with an `id` and simply storing that, but then I'm forced to adding an id to the element. Not elegant.)

### Anyone have any better ideas?

Comment: since `$elClone` is just an object, why not just do something like `$elClone.original = $elOriginal`? it would provide the same kind of functionality as `$elClone.context`, just a different kind of context

Comment: Well, adding a property to your cloned object is probably the best solution since `.data` is set to the DOM element.

Comment: @PlantTheIdea Sure enough. But is that really an improvement? Does it improve performance in any way?

Comment: @Karl-AndréGagnon But then if the original element is removed I would keep a reference to the a representation of an element that no longer exists... That may be useful or confusing.

Comment: As a note: If you do `$elClone.data('original', $elOriginal);` then jQuery adds an `id` to the `DOMElement` using an a _private_ property. This `id` is used to retrieve/store the _data_ from/to the private _cache_. Only that `id` is assigned to the `DOMElement`. Whenever (not only in your case)  you use `.data()` or event handlers in jQuery you need to make sure that you call the jQuery method `.remove()` on the elements you don't use anymore otherwise you will create memory leaks (until the page is reloaded). Look for the difference between `remove` and `detach` in the docs.

Comment: @Seebiscuit What would be the problem of keeping a reference to an non-existing object? Even if it doesn't exist in the DOM anymore, it is still the original one!

Comment: @Karl-AndréGagnon I didn't say that it is a problem, rather that it may lead to confusion if one expected the clone to refer to an element in the DOM. I did remark that your suggesting is _useful_.

Comment: @Seebiscuit My comment may have sound arrogant or something, but really, I was just asking how that could be confusing. I am not on a defensive stance. *(Just clarifying so it doesn't lead to an argument!)*

Comment: @Karl-AndréGagnon Lol, neither was I! I once read in a Google interview about recruitment that they look for people who ferociously stand their ground when they know they are right, and immediately stop and consider their position as soon as any new information is introduced. The whole purpose of my post was motivated by curiosity, so I'm all for the discussion.

Comment: @Karl-AndréGagnon In this case, I stand corrected. I misunderstood your first post. What `@PlantTheIdea` suggested is _similar_ to the `$.data()` solution. Except of course that a `$.remove` on my clone would evaporate the data store, while your object property would still survive. You're right, there's nothing confusing about that.

Comment: @Seebiscuit Indeed `$.remove` would erase the data saved, but you could also use `$.detach` which keep all events and datas. Both `.data` and adding a property has its advantages and disadvantages, but in your case, I would probably go with the property road. Again, I know nothing about your application and how it is used. You have the last call on what you should do! Just know that you should not feel *un-thrilled* using `.data`.

Answer (score 1):

Edit, Updated

jQuery's `prevObject` property appear to save reference to original object

Try (v3)

```
var $elOriginal = $("div");
var $elClone = $("div").clone(true, true);
$elClone.html(123);
$("body").append($elClone);
console.log($elClone.prevObject.html())
```

```js
    var $elOriginal = $("div");
    var $elClone = $("div").clone(true, true);
    $elClone.html(123);
    $("body").append($elClone);
    console.log($elClone.prevObject.html())
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div>abc</div>
```

Comment: Your solution sounds perfomant, but the **clone** does _not_ hold a reference to its source. Unless you suggest I make a stack for every clone/source pair and build a special case of a dictionary, where, say, `elems[0]` is the source and `elems[1]` is the clone. But, still, I was really looking for a solution that holds a reference to the source within the context of the clone jQuery object (or even better, the clone DOMElement).

Comment: @Seebiscuit Yes, initial approach was to create a pair for each original-clone pair , capable of being referenced utilizing `.eq()` method. Alternatively, `$(selector).prevObject` appear to hold reference to original element , following creation of clone . See updated post. Thanks

Comment: From what I found (and there's very little documentation out there on this) `prevObject` maintains a reference to the last object on a function chain. So this may not be a stable solution in the long run.

Comment: Utilized `prevObject` as it appeared to return desired results. Did not test with multiple elements , or include other conditions. If possible , can post link to documentation / descriptions found on jquery `prevObject` ? Thanks

Answer (score -1):

Use `withDataandEvents` and `deepWithDataAndEvents` to copy the events and data for the element and all children of the cloned element.

```
$elClone.clone(true, true);
```

From the [docs](http://api.jquery.com/clone/) -

> Normally, any event handlers bound to the original element are not copied to the clone. The optional withDataAndEvents parameter allows us to change this behavior, and to instead make copies of all of the event handlers as well, bound to the new copy of the element. As of jQuery 1.4, all element data (attached by the .data() method) is also copied to the new copy.
>   As of jQuery 1.5, withDataAndEvents can be optionally enhanced with deepWithDataAndEvents to copy the events and data for all children of the cloned element.

Comment: Ok, and how would I refer to the original element from the context of the clone?

Comment: Why would you need to?

Comment: In my case to preserve the sort of order of the list the original element is part of.

Comment: Why would making a clone of an element change the sort order of the original element within its original element?

Comment: This is not the point of the discussion, Jay. I don't have to go into the details of my implementation. Suffice to say that I need the original element index for a sort. The clone is part of a DIFFERENT list. But see now, I am going into my implementation...

Comment: No need for apologies, I'm sorry if I came off strong. In short, I'm plucking any number of clones from a master list and appending to an auxiliary list behind the scenes. The copy will happen repeatedly. Eventually the user will see this list and when that happens, the cloned elements which were copied to the aux list in any order have to sorted according to the original list.

Comment: This can be the way, only if you have no events that would colide.
AKA it copies events too which is sometimes unwanted behaviour :-)