# Is there a way to update a clone() source based on change to the cloned element in jquery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-clone

I have a cloned element that contains a checkbox input.  When the cloned element is unchecked, I need the source element to also be unchecked.  Is there a way to do this in jQuery? Or am I going about this the wrong way (i.e. using `clone()`)? I should mention that my question is similar to this [SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27488557/maintain-reference-in-jquery-clone-element-to-original-element) except I need to update the original element when the cloned element changes, not simply maintain a reference.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since it's a checkbox and you're specifically concerned with checking/unchecking the box, you can listen for the event '[change](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Events/change)' which will fire every time the box's `checked` status changes.

```
var copy = $('#my-element').clone();

copy.change(function(){
    $('#my-element').replaceWith(copy.clone());
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Add an event listener on the cloned element to update the original when it is changed.

something like this

```
var initial = $('some-element'),
    cloned = initial.clone();

cloned.on('change', function(){ 
    initial
        .prop('checked', this.checked)
        .trigger('change'); 
});
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
$(document).ready(function () {
 var $source = $("#source input[type='checkbox']");
 var $target = $source.clone(true, true);
 $("#target").append($target);
  
  // set current source value ..
  $($source).prop("checked", $target.prop("checked"));
  // update source to target and vice-verse, on change ...
 $target.change((event) => {
  $($source).prop("checked", $(event.target).prop("checked"));
 });
 $source.change((event) => {
  $($target).prop("checked", $(event.target).prop("checked"));
 });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="source">
  <span>source</span>
  <input type="checkbox"/>
</div>

<div id="target">
  <span>target</span>
</div>
```